# PHP - move_uploaded_file() unable to move /temp/ to actual folder in windows server

Tags: php, windows

PHP - move_uploaded_file() unable to move /temp/ to actual folder in windows server. Where as it is working fine in linux without issue. I have even given read write permission for the folders.

```
if(empty($_FILES['verifyfile']['name']))
{
    $path = 'No';
}
else
{
$name = $_FILES['verifyfile']['name'];
$tmp = $_FILES['verifyfile']['tmp_name'];

$path = "files/".basename($currentdatetime.$name);

move_uploaded_file($tmp,$path) ; // Moving Uploaded file
```

Error Log Given below

```
[14-Nov-2017 07:55:04 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Warning: move_uploaded_file(files/2017-11-14 07:55:04Sakthi APIL (Paid).pdf): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\verifydata.php on line 44 [14-Nov-2017 07:55:04 Asia/Kolkata] PHP Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\Windows\Temp\php9779.tmp' to 'files/2017-11-14 07:55:04Sakthi APIL (Paid).pdf' in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\verifydata.php on line 44
```

Comment: Your file name is wrong, windows does not support `:` in it's file names. Use this function to check whether the file name is correct or not =>      

 function check_file_uploaded_name ($filename)
{
    (bool) ((preg_match("`^[-0-9A-Z_\.]+$`i",$filename)) ? true : false);
}

Comment: Read the error. You can clearly see the temporary file was uploaded as expected `Unable to move 'C:\Windows\Temp\php9779.tmp'`. If you're sure the correct permissions are set, there's obviously another problem. `Invalid argument ... [14-Nov-2017 07:55:04 Asia/Kolkata]`. That should've given you a clue that the problem is within the name. Combine that with the fact that it works on a Linux server (so the code works fine) and you have a full recipe telling you what the problem is, as @ManishYadav correctly pointed out.